# how to auto restart node app after aws codeDeploy

Tags: node.js, travis-ci, aws-code-deploy

I have setup travis to aws codeDeploy for a node app. Now that the latest code can be deployed to EC2 correctly, but I need to manually restart the node app again to make the changes take effect.

How to auto restart the node app after codeDeploy? I guess I can do it by setting afterInstall in appspec.yml, but I find that many tutorial/walkthrough didn't mention about this, so I wonder is this the only/best way to restart the node app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pm2 or forever and you can restart your node after code deploy. Your appspec.yml should be as below

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: /deployment.zip
    destination: /home/ubuntu/PorjDir/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: stop_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
  AfterInstall:
    - location: start_server.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: ubuntu
```

Note: You need to create stop_server.sh and start_server.sh into your project and need to export it as artifact so code deploy agent can use it.

start_server.sh should contains below:

```
sudo /usr/bin/pm2 restart appname
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ApplicationStart hook in appspec.yml. From the AWS docs:

> AfterInstall – You can use this deployment lifecycle event for tasks such as configuring your application or changing file permissions.
>
> ApplicationStart – You typically use this deployment lifecycle event to restart services that were stopped during ApplicationStop.